# Resetting CSS for HTML for Input Form using Radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML/CSS to create tabbed content. This uses HTML input type="radio" and CSS as shown in the following snippet:

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; // make sure it wraps
}
.tabs label[name="tabs"] {
    order: 0; // Put the labels first
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#ddd;
    border-radius: 0 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#222;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    transition: background ease 0.2s;
}
.tabs .tab {
  order: 99; // Put the tabs last
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 0.0rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.tabs input[name="tabs"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs input[name="tabs"]:checked+label {
  background: teal;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tabs input[name="tabs"]:hover+label {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.tabs input[name="tabs"]:checked+label+.tab {
  display: block;
}

.tabcontent {
  width: 470px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 45em) {
  .tabs .tab,
  .tabs label {
    order: initial;
  }
  .tabs label {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
  }
}

.filtercontainer {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: teal;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper-left">
  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
    <label name="tabs" for="tabone">TAB 1</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="tabcontent">

        <div>
          <p>SEARCH FORM</p>
          <div class="filtercontainer">
            <form action="xxx.php" method="get">
              <input type="radio" id="A" name="type" value="A">
              <label for="A" >All</label>
              <input type="radio" id="P" name="type" value="P">
              <label for="P">Past</label>
              <input type="radio" id="F" name="type" value="F">
              <label for="F">Future</label><br><br> Phrase
              <input name="xx" type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" />
              <br><br>
              <input name="send" type="button" value="send" />
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>


        <div style="clear:left;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
    <label for="tabtwo" name="tabs">TAB 2</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="tabcontent">
        <p>
          Content for tab 2
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This all works fine, but the problem is that I want to use a Form with a regular Radio button within the tabbed content as shown in the snippet, but the code obviously picks up the CSS for the tabs. I have tried to create CSS specific for the Form/Radio buttons, but can't see how to reset it to the original for a radio button. Help appreciated.

NB: In this snippet I only have one tab but in my actual page I have two tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: just to explain some of the comments, in the initial answer I had misunderstood which inputs were to be styled 'teal etc' and which were to be kept to to the browser's default styling.

This snippet takes the updated snippet from the question which has two tabs and the nesting is clear that the unstyled tabs are hidden until their related TAB is clicked.

The need is to style TAB1 and TAB2 without styling the other inputs. There are various ways of selecting just those inputs, this snippet does it by noticing that they share a name attribute and selects on that.

```css
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; // make sure it wraps
}

.tabs
/*label*/

input[name="tabs"] {
  order: 1; // Put the labels first
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
}

.tabs .tab {
  order: 99; // Put the tabs last
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  padding: 0.0rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.tabs input[name="tabs"] {
  display: none;
}

.tabs input[name="tabs"]:checked+label {
  background: teal;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tabs input[name="tabs"]:hover+label {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color: #222;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tabs input[name="tabs"]:checked+label+.tab {
  display: block;
}

.tabcontent {
  width: 470px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
}

@media (max-width: 45em) {
  .tabs .tab,
  .tabs label {
    order: initial;
  }
  .tabs label {
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0.2rem;
  }
}

.filtercontainer {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: teal;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper-left">
  <div class="tabs">
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabone" checked="checked">
    <label for="tabone">TAB 1</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="tabcontent">

        <div>
          <p>SEARCH FORM</p>
          <div class="filtercontainer">
            <form action="xxx.php" method="get">
              <input type="radio" id="A" name="type" value="A">
              <label for="A">All</label>
              <input type="radio" id="P" name="type" value="P">
              <label for="P">Past</label>
              <input type="radio" id="F" name="type" value="F">
              <label for="F">Future</label><br><br> Phrase
              <input name="xx" type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" />
              <br><br>
              <input name="send" type="button" value="send" />
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>


        <div style="clear:left;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tabtwo">
    <label for="tabtwo">TAB 2</label>
    <div class="tab">
      <div class="tabcontent">
        <p>
          Content for tab 2
        </p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    This is ouside of the tabbed content
  </p>
  <div class="filtercontainer">

    <p>SEARCH FORM</p>
    <div class="radiobutton" style="padding: 20px 0">
      <form action="xxx.php" method="get">
        <input type="radio" id="A" name="type" value="A">
        <label for="A">All</label>
        <input type="radio" id="P" name="type" value="P">
        <label for="P">Past</label>
        <input type="radio" id="F" name="type" value="F">
        <label for="F">Future</label><br><br> Phrase
        <input name="xx" type="text" size="20" maxlength="15" />
        <br><br>
        <input name="send" type="button" value="send" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but unfortunately you appear to have misinterpreted what I am trying to do, no doubt due to my sloppy snippet! I have re-done my original snippet (also on JSFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/2swx0ert/2/) to demonstrate better what my problem.

Comment: Tabs 1 and 2 toggle as I expect. In the Tab 1 content I have inserted a Form for search purposes using radio buttons as one option. As you can see they radio buttons are styled the same as the tabs as they inherit the CSS from the tab/tabs styles. If you scroll down I have added the form again OUTSIDE the tabbed content where it displays as I want it. So, my question is how do you 'reset' the CSS within the tabbed content to get the radio buttons I want (and not tabs as currently displayed). Thanks

Comment: So it’s the other way round from what I had supposed? The three choices All, Past, Future are to look like default radio buttons and the TAB1 is to be the one that is styled?

Comment: Yes, Tab1 and Tab 2 are styled by the CSS displayed, and All, Past, Future should display as default radio buttons. I have no CSS for this as I don't know how to revert to the default.

Comment: Thanks, yes I had got things the wrong way round. I have changed the answer to use your updated snippet. I'm just not sure whether some of the CSS (the order part) should also still be applied to non-styled inputs - obviously in the snippet as it stands it doesn't matter but does it in real life?

Comment: Thanks @A Haworth. Just one problem - the tabs (Tab1/Tab2) are not picking up the correct styling. I have amended the CSS for .tabs /*label*/ input[name="tabs"] to .tabs label[name="tabs"] and named the labels in the HTML as "tabs". I also needed to change order from 1 to 0 to get it to work. I have amended my original snippet above to reflect these changes, and also at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w9082br3/. Thank you so much for getting me there.